# как при делегировании добавить класс другому элементу

Tags: javascript

Пробую сделать делегирование таким способом. Ставлю один обработчик событий на весь код. Первые два условия работают без проблем, но в третьем не могу добавить класс. В консоли выходит: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined. Почему? Или я не правильно делаю делегирование?

````
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('place-card__delete-icon')) {
    event.target.parentNode.remove();
  }

  if (event.target.classList.contains('place-card__like-icon')) {
    event.target.classList.toggle('place-card__like-icon_liked');
  }

  if (event.target.classList.contains('user-info__button-add')) {
    formAddPlace.classList.add('popup__new_is-opened');
  }
  if (event.target.classList.contains('user-info__button-edit')) {
    console.log("Clicked", event.target.textContent);
  }
});```
````

Comment: у  объекта  formAddPlace   нету свойства classList .  добавь, гды ты берешь  этот  объект

Comment: const formAddPlace = document.querySelector('.popup__new');

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll  возращает не элемент а  NodeList ([Дока](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList))

Отюда и проблема. У элемента NodeList не бывает поля classList.
Ты или индивидуально перебором  (через циклы или forEach - это если у тебя несколько элементов `.popup__new`) или если он один то `const formAddPlace = document.querySelector('.popup__new');`